# only showing top 20 rows

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-kafka-streams

I have a streaming dataset. It reads from Kafka stream and writes into console.

```
 val outputStream = inputStream.writeStream.format("console")
                    .option("truncate", value = false)
                    .option("checkpointLocation", "checkpoint")

 outputStream.start()

 spark.streams.awaitAnyTermination()
```

However when there are more than one record, I get  a message on console :
`only showing top 20 rows`

And it shows only 20 records. Is there a way to retrieve all records ??

Spark version : 3.1.2

Comment: try to use the following `.outputMode("complete")`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is an option `numRows`, for example: 10000.

```
val outputStream = inputStream.writeStream.format("console")
                    .option("truncate", value = false)
                    .option("numRows",10000)
                    .option("checkpointLocation", "checkpoint")
```